# react navigation and onPress

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, react-navigation

Hi Guys I am new to React native and I am trying to get my button to navigate to another screen called SignUpEmail.js, I am not getting any errors or anything but the button just does not redirect! I am using react navigation along with expo. I apologize for any ignorance! Let me know if you need anything else to assist me!

Also, do I want my WelcomePage inside of my render like that under App.js? Eventually I want to have a long stack of pages for a sign up registration. I think I am on the right track.

For Context

- GetStartedButton.js is my button on the WelcomePage that is supposed to direct to the SignUpEmailPage
- Welcome.js is my WelcomePage

I can add my SignUpEmail.js if you guys need it.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import WelcomePage from './src/pages/Welcome';
import SignUpEmailPage from './src/pages/SignUpEmail'

import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();


export default class App extends Component {
 
  createHomeStack = () =>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component= {Welcome}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUpEmail" component= {SignUpEmail}/>
  </Stack.Navigator>
 
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.welcomeScreen}>
       <WelcomePage/>
      </View>


    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  welcomeScreen: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black'  
  },
  signupemailScreen: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#272933' 

  }
}
);
```

Welcome.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Animated} from 'react-native';
import GetStartedButton from '../components/GetStartedButton';


export default class WelcomePage extends Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.fadeAnimation = new Animated.Value(0)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(this.fadeAnimation, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 5000,
      useNativeDriver: true,      
    }).start()
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerMain}>
        <View style={styles.containerClub}>
        <Animated.Text style={[styles.title, { opacity: this.fadeAnimation}]}>Clubbit</Animated.Text>
        </View>
        
      <View style={styles.containerCaption}>   
        <Animated.Text style={[styles.caption, { opacity: this.fadeAnimation}]}> The Real Time Nightlife Guide  </Animated.Text> 
      </View>
          
      <View style={styles.containerBottom}>   
      <GetStartedButton/> 
      </View>
    </View>

    );
    }
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    containerMain: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
    },

containerClub: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 288
  },

  containerCaption: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 250

  },
  /* To style the button and positioning*/
  containerBottom: {
    
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 100
  },
  /* To style "Clubbit"*/
  title: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 35,
    fontWeight: "bold",

  },
  /* To style "The Real Time Nightlife Guide"*/
  caption:
  {
   color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16
  },
  line: {
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor:'black',
     margin:10,
  }
}
)
```

GetStartedButton.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, Animated  } from 'react-native';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';

export default class GetStartedButton extends Component {
  
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
  
      this.fadeAnimation = new Animated.Value(0)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        Animated.timing(this.fadeAnimation, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 5000,
          useNativeDriver: true,      
        }).start()
      }

    render(){
        return(
        <Animated.View style={[styles.container, { opacity: this.fadeAnimation}]}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <LinearGradient   
                 
            colors={['#DB004C','#FC008E']}
            style={styles.linearGradient}
            start={{ x: 0, y: 0.5 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 0.5 }}
            >
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUpEmail')} >
                <Text style={styles.text}>
                    Get Started
                </Text>     
                </TouchableOpacity>
             </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity> 
        </Animated.View>
    )
    
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        
    },
    linearGradient: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderRadius: 10,
        width: 340,
        padding: 20,
    },

    text: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 20,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    }
});
```

Comment: Your component `GetStartedButton ` does not have prop `navigator`, you should pass it from `WelcomePage `. `WelcomePage` has it, because it is rendered by `Stack.Screen`

Comment: Sorry I have been away from my computer for the holidays, How would I go about passing it? Do I need to import something?